# Mojolicious response caching?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Hello I experimenting some small things with [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) and I have the following question:

- What happens when a request is received ?
- Is there some caching like in modperl or is the code compiled each time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the server it runs under.

If you use a pre-forking app server or fastcgi server then you'll get one or more processes re-used for multiple requests.

You can run a simple CGI, launching the script for each request, but it wouldn't be common.

Deployment options are in the [manual](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#DEPLOYMENT).